# make a vector of variable names from combinations of vectors

Tags: r

I have 4 vectors:

```
list1 <- c("a","b","c","d","e")
list2 <- c("f","g","h","i","j")
list3 <- c("k","l","m","n","o")
list4 <- c("p","q","r","s","t")
```

I want to generate every combination for choosing 2 of these 4 vectors, so I have used:

```
combs <- combn(c("a","b","c","d"),2)
```

I then want to run a function with those combinations (the columns of combs) as arguments:

so column 1 should give the combination of list1 with list2, but I want that as the vector "a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j" instead of "list1" "list2"

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please show the expected result. Maybe `combn(c(list1, list2), 2)`? PS: Please don't call vectors lists (even in variable names). That gets confusing as soon as you have actual list objects.

Comment: share output expected

Comment: Try `combn(paste0("list", 1:4), 2, FUN = function(x) list(mget(x, envir = .GlobalEnv)))`

Comment: The expected output is a vector containing "a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try

```
combn(paste0("list", 1:4), 2, FUN = function(x) 
                      unlist(mget(x, envir = .GlobalEnv)))
```

Comment: this does work but I have to use unlist(combn(paste0("list", 1:7), 3, FUN = function(x) list(mget(x, envir = .GlobalEnv)))[1]) to get the first combination.

Comment: @user3651829  In my code, it is `unlist(mget(x, ...`